# Can't make javah work with my Eclipse Android project

Tags: android, java-native-interface, java, javah

Ok, guys, I've read so many examples of javah usage and still got no luck.
I have Eclipse Android project, so I try following:

```
cd /path_to_project/
javah -classpath ./bin/classes com.package.ClassName
```

What I get:

```
class file for android.app.Activity not found
```

Ok, so, it sees my class and I just need to add android.jar to classpath:

```
javah -classpath ./bin/classes:path_to_sdk/android.jar com.package.ClassName
```

And I get:

```
Could not find class file for com.package.ClassName
```

"You're kidding me! You just saw it and now you can't find it!", I say.

Please, any help! I'm desperate here.

Tried compiling simple java class with javac and then using javah - it works fine.

**My environment:**
Windows 7, cygwin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll share what I've done to get javah to work for me. I hope it helps.

For example, I've got a project with a package name of 'com.android.MyProgram'. The activity source code file is located in the directory 'Path-To-Project/src/com/android/MyProgram' and the source code file is named 'MyProgram.java' and instantiates a class named 'MyProgram'. My native code is in the directory named 'Path-To-Project/jni'. I would use the following command line to run 'javah' for this project, run from the 'Path-To-Project' directory:

javah -cp src -d jni com.android.MyProgram.MyProgram

Again, I hope this helps.